# Removing some rows with respect to two columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to remove all rows whose mode is 2 and HH is 0.

```
                       mode      HH
                        2         0
                        2         1
                        3         4
                        2         0
                        2         1
                        2         2
```

output

```
                       mode      HH
                        2         1
                        3         4
                        2         1
                        2         2
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got several options.  First to build your dataframe:

```
mode = c(2,2,3,2,2,2)
HH <- c(0,1,4,0,1,2)
df <- cbind(mode, HH)
```

Now we can use:

`subset` like this `subset(df, mode != 2 | HH != 0)`

square brackets `df[which(mode != 2 | HH != 0),]`

`dplyr` function `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
as.data.frame(df) %>%
filter(mode != 2 | HH != 0)
```

Comment: why you used != ?

Comment: The `!=` symbol means "not equal" because you asked for the rows where mode is 2 and HH is 0 to be removed.  What output do you get running any of the options above?